# For every new text line separate, put that line into a div tag

Tags: php, html, css

I'm recently trying to integrate PHP, HTML and CSS into a website. Now, I'm trying to echo out this result that I get from a database into the website, where every new line/line break in the text is put into a div tag of its own.

Because I'm trying to make a checklist where the instructions for how to do something can be retrieved from the database and I'm using PHP to do that.

The data that will be retrieved is in TEXT format when retrieved, and looks something like this.

```
Perform this step
Then do this step
Lastly, do this step
```

So as you can see, each step takes up its own line and I can't figure out how exactly I can make it so that for every new line, it should rightfully be put into its own separate div tag in HTML that will have some CSS styling to change its appearance.

Does anyone know how? Or can they point me in the right direction? Is there an article similar to this because I haven't been able to find one.

If anyone requires more information I can edit the post but hopefully this post won't be shut down.

I'm open with any kind of solutions, but I would prefer not to use jquery unless it's absolutely necessary.

Thank you!

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: We won't do this for you, show what you tried and we will help you with that. You could make something work with http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php and a loop

Comment: As a hint you could use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to obtain an array of the lines.

Comment: or use a str_replace() to replace `\n` with `</li><li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step breaking the problem down into stages:

1) What you need is to break the text file up into "rows". Because different systems use different seperators for "rows" of text; you should use the `PHP_EOL` special constant.

2) Once split into rows, you then need to wrap these rows in the desired HTML formatting

3) and then recombine them into the output.

## so:

```
$parts = explode(PHP_EOL,$data);
foreach($data as $row){
     $row = "<div class='instructionStyling'>".$row."</div>\n";
}
unset($row);
$output = "<div class='instructionStyling'>".implode(PHP_EOL,$parts)."</div>";
```

> Perform this step
>      Then do this step
>      Lastly, do this step

Becomes:

> ```
> <div class='instructionStyling'>Perform this step</div>
> <div class='instructionStyling'>Then do this step</div>
> <div class='instructionStyling'>Lastly, do this step</div>
> ```

## Shorter Version:

```
$output = preg_replace("/\n+/i","</li><li>",$data);
$output = "<ul><li>".substr_replace($data,"</ul>",-4,4);
```

> ```
> <ul><li>Perform this step</li>
> <li>Then do this step</li>
> <li>Lastly, do this step</li></ul>
> ```

---

- Using style sheets and `li`/`ul` is preferential.
- processing the contents of the string means you do also need to wrap the finished string in HTML (`div`s or `ul`s, etc.)
- `\n` is a drop in replacement for `PHP_EOL` for clarity but `PHP_EOL` is recommended throughout